# Spring boot mongodb java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoException$DuplicateKey

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to create a spring boot application with mongodb. Here is the entity look like.

```
 import java.time.LocalDateTime;

 import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
 import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
 import javax.validation.constraints.Size;


import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;
 import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;


 @Document
 public class User  {

@Id
private String id;

@Size(min = 1, max = 128)
@Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z. ]*", message = "First name must contain valid character")
@NotNull(message = "First name can not be null")
@NotEmpty(message = "First name can not be empty")
private String firstname;

@Size(min = 1, max = 128)
@Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z. ]*", message = "Last name must contain valid character")
@NotNull(message = "Last name can not be null")
@NotEmpty(message = "Last name can not be empty")
private String lastname;

@NotNull
@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 6, max = 32, message = "Password must be six character long")
private String password;



@Indexed(unique = true)

private String email;


private LocalDateTime loginDate;


public LocalDateTime getLoginDate() {
    return loginDate;
}

public void setLoginDate(LocalDateTime loginDate) {
    this.loginDate = loginDate;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}




public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}


public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email.toLowerCase();
}



}
```

Here is the part of pom.xml that is responsible for the dependency.

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>





<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>



<dependencies>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-beta3</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
       <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
   </dependency>


   <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
```

The problem is I can insert users in the collections , and if try to add  duplicate email it throws errors as expected. 
But when I try to list the collection, I'm getting Duplicate key error.

```
 List<User>  users = MongoTemplate.getMongoOperations().find(query, User.class);
```

Here is the exception log,

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:54) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:1940) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1823) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1633) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1616) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:535) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:526) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar:na]

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81) ~[jersey-server-2.14.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151) ~[jersey-server-2.14.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:172) ~[jersey-server-2.14.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152) ~[jersey-server-2.14.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104) ~[jersey-server-2.14.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:384) ~[jersey-server-2.14.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:342) ~[jersey-server-2.14.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101) ~[jersey-server-2.14.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271) ~[jersey-server-2.14.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) ~[jersey-common-2.14.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) ~[jersey-common-2.14.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) ~[jersey-common-2.14.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) ~[jersey-common-2.14.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) ~[jersey-common-2.14.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297) ~[jersey-common-2.14.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254) ~[jersey-server-2.14.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1030) ~[jersey-server-2.14.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:377) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.14.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.14.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.14.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.14.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_31]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]
```

Can anybody help please ?

Update: 
Java 8 LocalDateTime was creating the problem. Posted the solution below in the in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

Milestone release fixed the problem.

```
  <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0.M1</version>
    </parent>
```

---

Cleaning up my pom.xml solve the problem for me. 
Removed ->

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
<exclusions>
<exclusion>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
</exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
```

And other unnecessary dependency
 pom.xml after clean up ->

```
      <pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>spring-snapshots</id>
    <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
  </pluginRepository>
<pluginRepository>
    <id>spring-milestones</id>
    <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
 </pluginRepositories>


   <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>miredot</id>
        <name>MireDot Releases</name>
        <url>http://nexus.qmino.com/content/repositories/miredot</url>
    </repository>


     <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>


     <repository>
    <id>spring-snapshots</id>
    <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
    <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
</repositories>


<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
 <version>1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>


   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>



   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>

    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Spring boot save your time with auto-configuration and also manage dependencies. In this case spring-boot's version 1.2.3.RELEASE use `mongo-java-driver` 2.12.5 and you are trying to use 3.0.0 where com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey doesn't exist as you can see in the documentation https://api.mongodb.org/java/2.13/com/mongodb/MongoException.DuplicateKey.html